# How can Ethereum be useful in Insurance Industry?

Tags: dao, insurance

How Ethereum can be useful to Insurance Industry ?

I'm a Web Developer, still learning about Smart Contracts, and familiar with Blockchain fundamentals to some extent.

Came across safeshareinsurance.com which will be giving insurance to slock.it projects.

I have to write some points and present to my manager how and what solutions can we build using blockchain tech today, and what innovative solutions can be offered to clients.

Cheers,
Satinder

Comment: peer to peer insurance, but this will bypass the insurance corporations.

Comment: Here's a link to the Dynamis peer-to-peer insurance whitepaper - http://dynamisapp.com/whitepaper.pdf . I don't know their situation is, but there is some interesting information in the document.

Answer (score 3):

The Smart Insurance Contract

This is getting most attention right now. The notion of automating the insurance policy once it is written into a smart contract is compelling. The idea that it will pay out against the insurable event without the policyholder having to a make a claim or the insurer having to administer the claim has significant attractions.

First, the cost of claims processing simply goes away. Second, the opportunity for fraud largely goes away too. (I hesitate on this one simply because it is theoretical and not yet proven). Third, customer satisfaction must go up!

One example being used to illustrate how these might work came from the London Fintech Week Blockchain Hackathon last September. Here a team called InsurETHbuilt a flight insurance product over a weekend on theEthereum platform.

The use case is simple. In the twelve months to May 2015, there were 558,000 passengers who did not claim for delayed or cancelled flights in and out of the UK. In fact, less that 40% of passengers claimed money back from their insurance policy.

They built a smart contract where the policy conditions were held on blockchain. Using the Oraclize service to connect the blockchain with the Internet, publicly available data is used to trigger the insurance policy.

In this case, a delayed flight is a matter of fact and public record. It does not rely on anyone’s judgement or individual assessment. It is what it is. If the event occurs, the smart contract gets triggered and the pay out is made. Automatic and immediate, with no claims processing costs for the insurer and satisfaction for the customer.

Building on this example and applying it to motor, smart contracts offer a solution for insurers to control claims costs after an accident. The trigger that there has been an accident would come from a smartphone app or the connected car via the Internet to the blockchain. Insurers are always frustrated when customers go a more expensive route for repairs, recovery and car hire. So, with a smart contract, insurers could code the policy conditions to only pay- out to the designated third parties (see related article by Sia Partners).

So long as the policy conditions are clear and unambiguous, and the conditions for paying out are objective, the insurance can be written in a smart contract. When the conditions are undeniably reached, the smart contract pays out. As blockchain startup SmartContract put it, “Any data feed trusted by a counterparty to release payment or simply complete an agreement, can power a smart contract.”

Font [Daily Fintech](http://dailyfintech.com/2016/01/14/what-does-the-future-hold-for-blockchain-and-insurance/)

Answer (score 1):

- Parametric insurance or CAT bonds. (If oracles determine there is an Earthquake or heavy rain in defined location in time period pay principle x else pay to y)
- Traditional Mutual insurance as a DAO with claims processing and loss adjustment outsourced to 3rd party service providers.
- Pooled Excess insurance. Traditional insurer offers cover to pool with high excess. P2P pool pay excess if claim accepted as genuine by traditional insurer.(Similar model to [Friendsurance](http://www.friendsurance.com) or [Guevara](https://heyguevara.com/) )
- Socially moderated community insurance pools (model similar to [Common Easy](https://www.commoneasy.nl/) or [TongJuBao](http://www.tongjubao.com/en/how-it-works-protect-each-other))
- Trading and issuance platforms for risk transfer contracts, Making these instruments more liquid and allowing a wider pool of people to invest or issue Alternative Risk Transfer or reinsurance instruments.
- Prediction markets may help improve pricing of risk or be used to hedge exposure.
- Storing data in a shared immutable database for example maintenance history may also interesting to existing insurers.

Most of these need stable currencies to work. Additionally some way of obtaining interest at low risk on locked up funds (e.g. staking) is required so that capital is efficiently employed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to prompt yourself to answer this question is: "what promises is the provider making to the client, that might be guaranteed by the code?"

The first thing that comes to mind in insurance is a promise of liquidity - the insurance company is promising that they will have cash in the future to cover the liabilities they take on.

An insurance company could maintain a reserve with some percentage of total liability, and the contract could enforce maintenance of the reserve by doing things like refusing new customer liabilities until the reserve is increased or preventing company profits from being removed if the reserve dips below some percent of the total liability.